# convert a month character value into a date month value

Tags: r, zoo, lubridate

I have a data frame with a month name character column and I need to convert it into a month name date column.  I try this code

```
data1$month <- as.Date(as.character(data1$month), "%B")
```

but all the values are turned into NA. what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

some more info on the data

```
head(data1)
month     year impressions clicks conversions    cost revenue month_num
<chr>    <dbl>       <int>  <int>       <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 April     2018    18737558 107063         291 117505. 145745.         4
2 August    2018    23247068 126523         439 118631. 143217.         8
3 February  2018    20119465 117370         320 146965. 114594.         2
4 January   2018    23905450 148205         382 155756. 145513.         1
5 July      2018    11963956  92740         297 106249. 138354.         7
6 June      2018     6845841  52294         253  53205.  91740.         6
```

Comment: Can you `dput(head(data1$month))` into a code block so we can see what you've got? If you truly only have a month name, that's not sufficient to make a `Date` object. You'd need to add a dummy day/year.

Comment: I added more info on the data, thanks

Comment: Try `as.Date(sprintf("%04d-%02d-01", data1$year, data1$month_num))`; it needs a "day" to be a `Date` so picking the first is a well-worn idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `match` the first three characters of the month name with the predefined vector `month.abb`:

```
data1$month_num <- match(substr(data1$month, 1, 3), month.abb)
```

Hope it helps.